# Two conditions in if statement in javascript does not appear to work correctly

Tags: javascript

I am unable to get a multiple if statement to work properly.

This is an extract of code from [TileBoard](https://github.com/resoai/TileBoard) for HomeAssistant.

Here's what I have:

```
   title: function (item, entity) {
       var start = entity.attributes.next_activity_start;
       var hold_state = entity.attributes.hold_state;
       var hold_until = entity.attributes.hold_until;
       if ( hold_state == "on" && hold_until == "null" ); { return 'N/A - Hold'; } return timeAgo(start);
   },
```

hold_state gets populated with "on" and hold_until gets populated with "null" which is exactly what I am expecting in this code. But, then the if clause seems to only really work properly by looking at the first condition, and not properly taking into account the second condition (hold_until == "null"). Am I using an incorrect syntax in this if statement? I'm wanting it to return "N/A - Hold" if hold_state is on AND hold_until is null.

Comment: It's because of the `;`juste after the if statement. remove it

Comment: Also `null  !== "null"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because, you are expecting a `string null`. Type expecting null without the string type, also remove the `;` after if case

```
if ( hold_state == "on" && hold_until == null ) { return 'N/A - Hold'; } return timeAgo(start);
```

Comment: Ahhhh!! That did it - removing the quotes from null and also removing the semicolon. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
 if ( hold_state == "on" && hold_until == "null" ); //this semicolon should be removed
 { 
    return 'N/A - Hold'; 
 } 

 return timeAgo(start)
```

Also look at your condition. I assume you want to check if your variable is **not** null:

```
if (hold_until != null && hold_state == "on")
```

Comment: If i remove the semicolon, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @bdf0506 please check updated answer

Comment: @bdf0506 `null !== "null"`, does hold_untill contains string `null` ?